# How to have multipe threads write to a file at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading

After watching a numberphile about persistence of a number, I decided to code it up. When I was doing it iteratively with a single core and saving the answers in a list running out of ram quickly because a problem so after the function ran I had it write directly to a file. After seeing taking a long time I decided to have it run multi core, however I knew ram was still going to be a problem so I would like it to keep writing directly to a file with the number and count of the persistence of the number. I know that not all the numbers will be in order, but I will deal with that later. Currently I would like for the code just to write everything to the file. Here is my code, I know it is a bit of a mess:

```
import time
import math
from multiprocessing import Pool

# global f

def fun(num):
    mult = 1
    lis = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
    for i in lis:
        mult *= i
    return mult

def fun1(num):
    count = 0
    while len(str(num)) > 1:
        num = fun(num)
        count += 1
    return count
    # with open(f"asnwers/answers{num}.txt", "w") as f:
    #     f.write(f"[{temp}, {count}]\n")

def fun2(num):
    result = fun1(num)
    with open("results.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write(f"[{num}, {result}]\n")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    upper_bound = 10**2
    numbers = range(upper_bound)
    start = time.time()
    p = Pool()


    # results = p.map(fun1, numbers)
    p.map(fun2, numbers)

    p.close()
    p.join()


    end = time.time()
    # print(results)
    with open("results.txt", "r") as f:
        things = f.read()
    print (things)
    print("The time of execution of above program is :",
        (end-start) * 10**3, "ms", math.log10(upper_bound))
```

Here are my results currently.

```
[0, 0]
[2, 0]
[18, 1]
[[6, 0]
[11, 1]
[30, 1]
[54, 2]
[34, 2]
[40, 1]
[51, 1]
[35, 2]
[74, 3]
[85, 2]
[96, 3]
[98, 3]
[95, 3]
```

Here is the numberphile vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wim9WJeDTHQ.

Comment: It's not reasonable that this sort of program would run out of memory, so you might want to address that problem instead.  Beyond that, what's the question here?  Your current results seem to be what you want.

Comment: That makes since about sorting it, however i should clarify that I do not play on sorting it just analyzing part of it at a time. Sorry I posted the wrong output; it should have all the numbers less than 100.

Comment: If you posted the wrong output, _update_ your post, don't just leave the wrong information in it. Rewrite it so that start to finish it reads like a proper post, don't slap an "edit" at the end: your post is a question, not an answer that needs an edit years later when the technologies/APIs/etc in question have changed.

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I get the expected output (thanks to [things like `O_APPEND`](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/08/03/)).  On what platform are you running this?

Comment: I am running this on windows.